# mailing problem

Tags: php, email

thanks a lot for helping for previous one.
now another is here.
this is the response when i try to run the code.

```
<h3>copy of this order has been emailed to you for your records.</h3>
<?php echo $html_body;
//send email
$headers = array();
$headers[]= 'MIME-Versioon: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html;charset="iso-8859-1"';
$headers[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit';
$headers[] = 'From: <priyambikap@gmail.com>';
$headers[] ='Bcc: <priyambika@hotmail.com>';
mail($email,"OrderConformation",$html_head.$html_body,join("\r\n",$headers));
```

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for y4yogeshtanwar@gmail.com in C:\xampp\htdocs\flowers\checkout3.php on line 388

bottom line is that i know nothing about how to configure server to be useful for php scripting.i am using xampp for developing this app.

Comment: your mail server is not configured correctly with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are  using your gmail address as the outgoing address.

That can't work, and if it did, your mails would get caught in any decent spam filter.

You need to specify a valid sender address on the domain the PHP script runs on.

Comment: actully i m checking if script is working properly.will it work when i provide valid domain.

Comment: @pri there's only one way to find out.

Comment: how can i client is still not sure but i need to know where am i wrong or i m sertainly missing something.its frustating.

Comment: @pri what is keeping you from simply entering a valid sender E-Mail address in the "from" field?

Comment: this is valid what do u mean by valid?
is it shoud be like "www.example.com".i dont have aome thing like this.

Comment: @priya As I said above, "You need to specify a valid sender address on the domain the PHP script runs on". Some E-Mail address on that domain.